# Wordpress site give 504 bad Gateway while html and php file is working

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-504

I have a server of my client and I deployed my WordPress website to it using an FTP account, when I try to open My WordPress website I keep getting 504 Bad gateway error as the following screenshot

[image]

I tried to add a simple HTML document and it works, also I have been attempting to add a test PHP file with phpinfo inside it and it works also, but the WordPress is not working

I also tried to disable app plugins and the same problem remains
Can anyone advise me on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to the site URL settings in wp-config? Info here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

- Go /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.
- Change the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.
- Restart the apache server.